# How to log the browsing history by packet sniffing?

Tags: python, packet-sniffers

I would like to log my browsing history in a separate file. I would like to do this by logging the network traffic and in specific the HTTP get requests originating from my PC. I would like to do this in Python but I have no idea where to start with.

Comment: You want to write your own program for some reason or are you just looking for a tool which does that? [dsniff](http://monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/) has an urlsnarf tool which does exactly that.

Comment: Urlsnarf works like charm. i can dump the data to file and read it back in python but a python wrapper would be straight forward. I can partially accept this as an answer.

Comment: You could also use a proxy and log all requests. Maybe this is easier...

Comment: @javex what exactly you mean by proxy? creating a proxy to sniff get requests is hard way to do it.

Comment: If it is your own browser, you create a proxy (or get an existing one) and enter its address (e.g. `localhost:8080`) into your browser. All request will be redirected via your proxy and you can analyze all packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned, you can use the *urlsnarf* tool from [dsniff](http://monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/) as a pretty straight-forward solution. If you aren't looking for a strictly-Python solution, you can easily wrap it from Python.

To get a real-time output, you can run it directly using `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('urlsnarf', stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    while True:
        l = p.stdout.readline()
        # ...
finally:
    p.terminate()
```

But that would require your user to have necessary permissions for packet sniffing. If you will want to run it as root, it would be probably better to run urlsnarf separately and just pipe the output through a named pipe.

First, with root permissions (in shell):

```
mkfifo /home/youruser/tmp/urlsnarf-pipe
chown youruser /home/youruser/tmp/urlsnarf-pipe
urlsnarf > /home/youruser/tmp/urlsnarf-pipe
```

Then simply read the pipe from within a Python script (run as your user):

```
f = open('/home/youruser/tmp/urlsnarf-pipe', 'r')
while True:
    l = f.readline()
    # ...
```

Comment: I went with straight forward method. Included an entry in root crontab as "@reboot urlsnarf -i p33p1 >> file.clob". Thanks for the python wrapper, it is really nice.